# React router make middle part url "movable"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have possible urls in browser:

```
/en/shop/hiper-product-name-12344
/en/shop
/en/basket/shop/hiper-product-name-12344
/en/blog/title-article
/en/basket/blog/title-article
```

I want to make `basket` movable,  optinal in middle url? I'm using react-router-dom-v6

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routers>
      <Route path="/:lang" element={<App />}>
         <Route path="/shop" element={...}>
            <Route path="/:product" element={...}>
            </Route>
         </Route>
         <Route path="/blog" element={...}>
            <Route path="/:article" element={...}>
            </Route>
         </Route>
      </Route>
   </Routers>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I think to add route component in "lang" and add path like "basket or null", but how inform about his Route?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add & handle "optional" route path params you will need to explicitly define a route and path for them.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/:lang" element={<App />}>
      <Route path="/shop" element={...}>
        <Route index element={...} />
        <Route path="/:product" element={...} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/blog" element={...}>
        <Route path="/:article" element={...} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/basket">
        <Route index element={...} />              // "/:lang/basket"
        <Route path="/shop" element={...}>         // "/:lang/basket/shop"
          <Route path="/:product" element={...} /> // "/:lang/basket/shop/:product"
        </Route>
        <Route path="/blog" element={...}>         // "/:lang/basket/blog"
          <Route path="/:article" element={...} /> // "/:lang/basket/blog/:article"
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: But what about (this is short wersion )`<Route path="/:lang/basket?/shop" component={...} />`? Ifound that `?` mark make parameter optional. But I think how does `Route` know that I mean an address without a `basket`...

Comment: Btw, I thought that I could put this repeating fragment into a separate component and link it in that two places

Comment: @Peter `react-router-dom@6` `Route` components don't handle optional parameters or Regular Expressions in the `path` prop. See [What Happened to Regexp Routes Paths](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths) for explanation. This was a feature available in previous versions of RRD. Yes, you could certainly **DRY**-ify what are effectively duplicate sub-routes into a component, just keep in mind that *that* component will need to render them into another `Routes` component so descendent route matching can continue working.